# jquery: select elements except own children

Tags: jquery

I need to select elements of a certain class except children of $(this). The trick is no elements have an id attribute and the classes of parent and children elements are the same, so

```
<div class="onedoc">1
    <div class="onedoc">1.1
        <div class="onedoc">1.1.1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="onedoc">1.2</div>
</div>
<div class="onedoc">2</div>
<div class="onedoc">3</div>
```

in this example, if $(this) is 1 (the first element), I need to select elements containing 1.1.1, 2 and 3

Comment: `1.1.1` is grand-child of `1`. Did you mean, select elements without children?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: I assume he means children to be immediate descendents, rather than those further down the line.

Comment: @JonEgerton Thought so, but then `1.1.1, 2 and 3` won't include `$(this)`. Is that the expected behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$('.onedoc').not($(this).children());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6FDMd/)

Comment: But the first element doesn't (and can't) have an id (re your demo)

Comment: @DMIL The ID is simply there so the demo can simulate already having access to `this`, which is implied by the question to already be known.

Comment: It's nice and clean, and you can reference it [without an ID as well](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/6FDMd/1/).

Comment: Thanks, that works but not for what I need it for. I'm trying to use it with jquery-ui droppable and apparently it won't accept this selector. Thanks anyway, now I'm closer to finding the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.onedoc:not(:has(.onedoc))');
```

You can specify the target by doing this:

```
 $('.onedoc:not(:has(.onedoc))', $target); // where $target is some element you selected
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HackedByChinese/PqxbL/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jquery remove()`: http://api.jquery.com/remove/.

Select all the `onedoc` elements, then remove the child elements from the DOM using `remove()`

e.g.

```
$('.onedoc').remove($(this).children());
```

Edit as per comments: If you don't want to include the node itself, then remove that too:

```
$('.onedoc').remove($(this).children()).remove($(this));
```

Comment: Actually I prefer @Anthony's answer - might be a little more optimal than mine.

Comment: Message: Object doesn't support property or method 'replace'... even if I typed remove

Comment: Again the same Javascript error: Object doesn't support property or method 'replace'

Comment: That's clearly a issue with how you're using is. You'll need to post more of what you're doing.